# Creating and Saving objects in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to create a game using C++ / SDL / OpenGL and Box2D and I was wondering if I can create objects and save them to use later.

To be more precise, I want to create a map this way :
When I click somewhere in the window, it creates an object of my choice (a wall, a ground, etc..) and it will save it into a file that I can use to display the map. 
It would save me much time as I will not have to set the x and y positions, length, rendering and all this shit manually and open debugger each time, then re-adjusting, etc.. 
So, can I do this and if so, how can I do it ?

Comment: This is called "serialization" and C++ is not supporting this out-of-the-box. You have to implement the logic yourself. However, that is not easy.

Comment: Hi, There are many approaches to this, and your question is too broad for this forum.  Serialization is just one tiny slice of it.   Anyway, why reinvent the wheel? There are tools to do this; I would start by searching for relevant questions on Worldbuilding SE or even GIS SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is insanely vague.

Long answer: YES, you can turn your game into a map editor, there is no "built-in" way to do that. You will have to write all editor/serialization logic yourself. You should use a game engine like Unity or Unreal if you want to achieve this kind of features/Behaviour out of the box.

Short anwser: WHY BOTHER doing so, knowing awesome map editors like ["Tiled"](https://www.mapeditor.org/) exists exactly for this purpose, and lots of binding to read maps exists in numerous languages on github.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand the concept. I may have a look on Unity but for now, I'm just doing this for fun and learning